# Haskell - Module not found (hidden package)

Tags: haskell, module, package, hidden, cabal

I recently installed the Haskell Platform for Windows for a programming class I'm taking. It includes GHCi as a compiler and Cabal as a packaging system. I've been trying to install the Craft3e package with Cabal, as this is the exercise package that my textbook uses, but to no avail. 
To install Craft3e, I just enter `cabal unpack Craft3e` in the command prompt, which creates the directory "\Craft3e-0.1.0.8". After entering the directory, I type `cabal install --disable-documentation`, which gives me the following message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed: 
time-1.2.0.5 (new version)
random-1.0.1.1 (reinstall) changes: time-1.4 -> 1.2.0.5
QuickCheck-2.5.1.1 (reinstall)
Craft3e-0.1.0.8 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken b
haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

After using `cabal install --disable-documentation --force-reinstalls`, it install as expected. I load a module to test it out: `ghci PicturesSVG`. This loads successfully. However, once I quit the GHCi compiler and go back into it, I can no longer load the modules from the Craft3e packages; instead, I get the message:

```
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

<command line>:
    Could not find module `PicturesSVG'
    it is a hidden module in the package `Craft3e-0.1.0.8'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
 Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What happened? The package still shows up when I enter `ghc-pkg list`. I've tried entering `ghc-pkg expose Craft3e-0.1.0.8`, but the prompt tells me:

```
WARNING: cache is out of date: C:/Program Files (x86)/Haskell Platform/2012.4.0.
0\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
  use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
```

I've done the recache, and re-entered the "expose" command, but still no results.

Any solutions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken b
haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0
```

That is a *very* bad sign. You should only use `--force-reinstalls` if you know very well what you're doing, which, as a new learner, you more or less by definition don't. `cabal` should probably warn more sternly.

The root of the problems is that the package's dependencies are specified too strict for it to work with ghc-7.4 or later by default, as they come with a `time` package version that is larger than allowed by `craft3e`'s `.cabal` file. The proper fix for that problem would have been to relax the dependency bound on `time` (should have been done by the author, but before a fixed version is on hackage, the user should edit the `.cabal` file to allow `time-1.4.*` if (s)he has a `ghc >= 7.4`, so the package can be built without reinstalling anything and thereby probably breaking installed packages).

The reinstall of `time`, `random` and `QuickCheck` likely broke a number of packages, run `ghc-pkg check` from the command line to get an assessment of the damage. Maybe just `ghc-pkg unregister`ing `time-1.2.0.5` and reinstalling `random` and `QuickCheck` would fix it, maybe you need to reinstall more, perhaps the entire platform.

After the broken packages have been fixed one way or another, go to the `Craft3e-0.1.0.8` directory, edit the `Craft3e.cabal` file, changing the line

```
time >= 1.1 && < 1.3,
```

in the `build-depends` field to

```
time >= 1.1 && < 1.5,
```

and run `cabal install --disable-documentation` there.

---

```
Could not find module `PicturesSVG'
it is a hidden module in the package `Craft3e-0.1.0.8'
```

Right. The package doesn't expose any modules, so all modules it comes with are hidden (not sure whether that's really intended). You can load them only from the directory they are in, since ghci prefers loading source files from the current directory (tree) to package modules. If you invoke ghci from that directory, it should load the file. (Or you can also specify the path to the directory when invoking ghci from another directory, `ghci -ipath/to/Craft3e-0.1.0.8 PicturesSVG`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with your last suggestion is that I'm eventually going to need to import those modules in my own programs, and I won't be able to specify the path then... or will I? Is there a way to expose the modules?

Comment: You could still specify the path with an `-i` flag. But of course, you could also expose the modules, just comment out or remove the `other-modules` line in the `.cabal` file.

Comment: Just an update: I reinstalled the entire platform and re-downloaded the package, and I edited the .cabal file to reflect the changes you specified. After that, I tried to install the package, but it didn't work. Something about the package requiring multiple version of "time".

Comment: Argh, I checked only `cabal build`, with `cabal install`, I think it checks the `.cabal` file for the package in the (local copy of the) hackage index. You may need to bump the package version too in the `.cabal` file. Further, it could indicate that your old user package db is still around. That would probably be somewhere under `Users\You\AppData` or so, find the path with `ghc-pkg list` That prints out the location of the global package db an its contents, and then the same for the user db. On Linux, the user db is usually somewhere like `/home/user/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.1/package.conf.d`

Comment: On Windows, the first part of the path would be different, the last parts should be identical. Remove the user `package.conf.d` if that is still the old one.

Comment: Just a quick question: when you say "...the user should edit the .cabal file to allow time-1.4.* for ghc >= 7.4", does that mean that I should write "ghc >= 7.4" somewhere?

Comment: @user1730404 No, I meant "when the user has ghc >= 7.4 (with time-1.4.*), then the user should edit the `.cabal` file (to allow the installed version of `time`)".

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help so far Daniel! I'll have to try the rest of your advice when I get home, and I'll write down the results. :)

Comment: So I reinstalled everything again, this time deleting every single file relating to Haskell (including the package db). Still no dice.
What do you mean by the following: "Argh, I checked only cabal build, with cabal install, I think it checks the .cabal file for the package in the (local copy of the) hackage index."? I've been using `cabal install` the whole time.

Comment: When I made sure that the package compiles with `time-1.4.0.1`, I used `cabal configure` and then `cabal build`, and not `cabal install`. When you wrote that it complained about something depending of multiple versions, I thought that might have something to do with that (too little sleep, that would give a different message). So with the modified `.cabal` file it builds without problems here. If not for you, you must have something left lying around. Most probably in the package directory, the built package. Try `cabal clean` before `cabal install`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Craft3e` packege [doesn't actually expose *any* modules](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Craft3e/0.1.0.8/Craft3e.cabal). The cabal file seems to be there mostly for distribution- and dependency purposes, not to give you a proper library interface, so to load any of the modules you always need to open explicitly the file where it's included.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the Craft3e package to take into account the new version of Time. Apologies for any problems caused.